# mingw32-make opencv cmake 3rdparty,the pathname of adler32.c.obj was unfound

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, codeblocks, mingw-w64

I want to Install OpenCV for codeblocks for C++
I follow this tuto:
http://kevinhughes.ca/tutorials/opencv-install-on-windows-with-codeblocks-and-mingw/
After the build of openCV with cmake, I use the cmd command.

when I do:
 C:\opencv\buid\x86\mingw>mingw32-make.exe
there is a problem in the:
C:\opencv\build\x86\mingw\3rdparty\zlib\CMakeFiles\zlib.dir
==> the file "adler32.c.obj is unfounded.
For sure, this file doesn't exist. 
How can I get this file ?

your answer could be really helpfull, I hope there is a solution to solve it

Comment: 'adler32.c.obj' is quite unlikely.  Do you mean 'adler32.obj', which is part of zlib?

Comment: @ravenspoint, I think `adler32.c.obj` is what CMake calls the object file for `adler32.c`.